# Where clause query using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.3

I am having this code working correctly `$sector = Sector::where('ref_id', $sectorId)->with('offers.provider')->first();` which has been changed to the code below for more flexibility and more understanding of what I want to do:

```
$sector = Sector::where('ref_id', '$sectorId')
->with(
    [
        'offers' => function($query) {
            $query->with(
                [
                    'provider' => function($query) {
                        $query->select('name');
                    }
                ]
            );
        }
    ]
)
->first();
```

So here we are taking a `sector`, the `offers` link to this `sector` and under each `offer`, we are taking the linked `provider`. Now, `providers` are having a `status` which is either `0` or `1`. So based on my code above, is there a way to retrieve ONLY `offers` which are having `providers` with the status of `1` ?

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) - which is specifically designed to work for scenarios like this. The example from the docs:

> If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries. These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment:

```
// Retrieve all posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

Don't let the snippet fool you, it'll work perfectly well inside a `closure` as you have above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a where clause inside the provider query to fetch only providers with a status of 1?

```
'provider' => function($query) {
    $query->select('name')->where('status', 1);
}
```

EDIT: I'm no expert at Laravel but maybe an example of a query I had trouble with might shed some light on your problem:

```
$dealer = $this->dealer->where('foreign_dealer_id', $dealerIdInFeed)
            ->where(function ($subQuery) use ($accountTypes) {
                if(count($accountTypes) > 1)
                {
                    foreach($accountTypes as $accountType)
                    {
                        $subQuery->orWhere('account_type', $accountType);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $subQuery->orWhere('account_type', $accountTypes);
                }
            })
            ->first();
```

Comment: I updated my answer with something that might help you understand how to solve your problem.

Comment: It might also help to show what your table structure looks like in your database.